# IMAP Service in front of Pop3

Tags: email, imap

I'm running a system that includes integrated email support (Synchronet), and while there's an in progress IMAP service in progress, it's rather buggy and doesn't seem to work well with Thunderbird at least.

I'm curious if anyone is aware of an IMAP server software that basically provides indexing over messages that are parked on POP3?  In this way the existing POP3 service could remain but have an IMAP service with directories over the top.

I have tried searching Google and Bing, but get too many results that aren't even close to what I'm looking for.  A software for this, or a configuration example that shows how to configure such a beast would be appreciated.

Comment: Would have added pop3 as a tag, but don't have the rep on this site yet.

Comment: POP3 is download only. IMAP allows messages to be added to a mailbox. You could pull all the messages out of the POP3 mailbox into your own IMAP server, but that's then just something like `fetchmail` and `dovecot` and POP3 is left just as an unwanted extra item in the delivery loop

Comment: @roaima I get that... didn't really even know where to start.  Since searching the generic terms delivers everything but what I'm wanting to do.